# Need to parse the current directory a batch file is in into a variable I can use in said batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, rsync, cwrsync

Working with rsync on a windows machine (cWrsync) and I am syncing a large folder with sub directories to a web server which takes several minutes to complete. But when the user just needs to add a file to a sub-directory I don't want them to have to wait an hour to sync that directory.

My Idea
Add a file into each sub-directory (1_sync.bat) that they can execute when they add or delete a file within that directory. I need the batch file to be able to dynamically tell rsync which directory to sync.. here is the static version:

```
@echo off
REM Make environment variable changes local to this batch file
SETLOCAL

REM where ti find rsync and related files
SET CWRSYNCHOME=C:\cwRsync

SET HOME=C:\Users\greg\AppData\Roaming

SET CWORLDPATH=%PATH%
SET PATH=%CWRSYNCHOME%\BIN;%PATH%

"C:\cwRsync\bin\rsync.exe" -v -e 'ssh -i C:\home\greg\.ssh\id_rsa' --delete --recursive --inplace  "/cygdrive/z/1CustomerDocs/2017/Client Folder/" "root@domainname.com:/var/storage/customer_files/2017/Client\ Folder/"
```

In the above example I would like to have Client Folder be a variable that will detect what folder the batch script is actually in so I can just through one of the bat files in every sub directory.

I tried %~dp0 which almost does the trick, but outputs the entire path.. I just need the last two directories.

so if %~dp0 = \SERVER-PATH\Content\1CustomerDocs\2017\Client Folder\

I wish I could cut the last two directories off and have a variable that looks like

2017/Client Folder (but also need one that escapes the spaces for linux)

So the end results would look like

```
@echo off
REM Make environment variable changes local to this batch file
SETLOCAL

REM where ti find rsync and related files
SET CWRSYNCHOME=C:\cwRsync

SET HOME=C:\Users\greg\AppData\Roaming

SET CWORLDPATH=%PATH%
SET PATH=%CWRSYNCHOME%\BIN;%PATH%

SET CUST_FOLDER_WINDOWS=*YOUR HELP NEEDED HERE*
SET CUST_FOLDER_LINUX=*YOUR HELP NEEDED HERE*

"C:\cwRsync\bin\rsync.exe" -v -e 'ssh -i C:\home\greg\.ssh\id_rsa' --delete --recursive --inplace  "/cygdrive/z/1CustomerDocs/%CUST_FOLDER_WINDOWS%" "root@domainname.com:/var/storage/customer_files/%CUST_FOLDER_LINUX%"
```

And again, I would need the linux folder to escape spaces.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

To be independent from the current dirlevel:

```
@echo off
Echo current dir %CD%
Echo Batch dir   %~dp0
for %%a in ("%~dp0.")  Do Set "Parent=%%~nxa"
for %%a in ("%~dp0..") Do Set "Grandparent=%%~nxa"

Echo Last 2 dirs \%Grandparent%\%Parent%
```

---

```
current dir Q:\Test\2017\08\10
Batch dir   Q:\Test\2017\08\10\
Last 2 dirs \08\10
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it how below

```
@echo off
REM Make environment variable changes local to this batch file
SETLOCAL


REM where ti find rsync and related files
SET CWRSYNCHOME=C:\cwRsync

SET HOME=C:\Users\greg\AppData\Roaming

SET CWORLDPATH=%PATH%
SET PATH=%CWRSYNCHOME%\BIN;%PATH%

for /F "tokens=5,6 delims=\" %%a in ("%0") do (
"C:\cwRsync\bin\rsync.exe" -v -e 'ssh -i C:\home\greg\.ssh\id_rsa' --delete --
recursive --inplace  "/cygdrive/z/1CustomerDocs/%%a/%%b/" 
"root@domainname.com:/var/storage/customer_files/%%a/%%b/"
)
```